# Animation Nodes: How can I rotate a Vector around a given Point

Tags: animation-nodes, mathematics, geometry-nodes, vector-mapping, vector

I was wondering how I could rotate a simple 3D Vector around a given point in 3d Space.

I am trying to rotate a simple position Vector (1,-2,1) around the world Center (0,0,0) on the Z Axis. If I rotate this vector around 180 degrees on the Z-Axis it should result in a new position vector (-1,2,1).

Geometry nodes is offering the Vector Rotate Node (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/vector_rotate.html?highlight=vector%20rotate)

Is there something similar in Animation Nodes? Or Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Transform Vector` node for doing any kind of transformation.

[image]